# Onselect formula

Tags: formula, powerapps

I am using the Service Desk template in Microsoft PowerApps.

However, I would like to modify the Dashboard with a date picker (called “DatePicker2”)

For “All tickets” there is this Onselect formula;
**If(ThisItem.TicketTypes="All tickets";UpdateContext({type:"All"});**

I would like to show all tickets, but based on the value in DatePicker2 (correlates to the CreatedDate in the “Tickets”- table.

Any ideas on how to modify the Onselect formula?

Best regards Ola

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I modified the OnSelect formula as following and worked:

**If(ThisItem.TicketTypes="All tickets",UpdateContext({datetype:Text(DatePicker2.SelectedDate),type:"All"});**

You will also need to update the formula for the Items in TicketsGallery to:

**If(type="All",Filter(Tickets,datetype in DateCreated)**

Comment: Hi Laura
Thank you for the help, you made my day ;)

Comment: Hi again Laura, do you know an easy whey to make the count row function(Texbox) in the template to updated based on the date in date picker ? :)